# Change the display of integer output

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a maze and robot with `vector` of `vector`. However, I also want to use `bool` to display the wall so the robot cannot walk through it. And my `vector` display with 0 and 1 only.

I want to change from `0` to `.` without using `char` or changing any element in `vector` to another type. I remember there is a guy who changed it with ASCII and using library `windown.h` but I can't remember how to do it. Can anyone help?

```
000000000000 
000000000000 
000000000000
```

Should be

```
............
............
............
```

Comment: Search for a "curses" library. Those allow you to write code to render ASCII drawings like used by roguelikes for various terminals.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: If you have a PC with the OEM character set, you could have even more fun with the line drawing characters. IIRC these also have Unicode code points (hopefully someone will confirm), so you could do a reasonably portable job.

Comment: Replying to myself: yes, that characters set is code page 437.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you gave us some more context it would be easier for us to help you, but in theory you should be able to display a `'.'` or `' '` character conditionally based on the boolean value. For instance, if the bool you want to print is in the variable `cellIsWall` then printing the expression `(cellIsWall ? '.' : ' ')` will print a dot if the value is true and a space if the value is empty.

Of course, this assumes you are using `printf` or `std::cout` or a similar function for printing your maze, if you are using an internal Windows API function which accepts an array of bools then you will need to give us more information.